# How to clear all Javascript function in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I'm just new in android webview. In my application's webview, It's some Javascript functions for some specific native buttons which is interacted with Webview. However, my problem is, there are so many function in a single webview. I have to check a lot a coditions to detect which funtion is using or not. Can anybody let me know how to reset or clear all Javascript function in webview android?

Comment: You can try to group functions in object based on their role/scope/page and access accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

by default javascript is disable in web view, you can enable it using this method `void setJavaScriptEnabled (boolean flag)`
check out Doc for this method

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean)